# Reason for friendship between Indra and Takshaka

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, indra, naga

Takshaka and Indra are friends as per Mahabharata Khandava Vana burning episode. Is there any specific reason for their friendship?

Comment: http://www.transliteral.org/dictionary/tak%E1%B9%A3aka-i/word provide details about How Takṣaka became Indra's friend... but not sure from where the story is taken as Indra seems helping Utanka in recovering ear-rings in http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01004.htm

Comment: Reference: Mahabharata-Adiparva-Mayadarshana Parva-Adhyaya 227 (Nivrtteshwatha deveshu vaguvacashareerinee. Shatakratum samabhashya mahagambheera ni:swanaa.    Na the sakha sannihitah Takshako bhujagottamah. Dahakale khandavasya kurukshetram gato hyasow